# Wrong addition result when adding float and int

Tags: c, addition

I have quite an unusual problem, that is probably just bad code from a newbie C-learner. I am struggling with the following piece of code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv) {
    float a = 1587128832.000000;
    int d = 1587128898.000000;
    float f = a + d ;
    printf("%f\n", f);
    return 0;
}
```

The following code outputs `3174257664.000000` while google [says that the result should be 3174257730](https://www.google.com/search?q=1587128832.000000%20plus%201587128898.000000).

I am trying to add a `float`/`double` with an `int` and it is giving me a strange result.

So what the heck am I doing wrong?

I don't think that the error is in fact a problem with mixed datatypes, as C should convert `int`s to `float`s.

Comment: If `float` on your system is 32 bits, then it has only 6 or at most 7 significant decimal digits. Your initializers have far more than 6 or 7 significant digits.

Comment: [Tom Scott - floating point numbers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZRI1IfStY0&t=273s) might help you

Comment: @phonetagger Thank you, after using double it works. Should I delete this or keep it for SEO?

Comment: If you use `double` this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: At last count, this question or variations of it had been asked 115,640,000 times on SO. But that count may have been suffering from a rounding error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

float is not capable of holding exactly such numbers.[image]

viz. https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html

if you want exact result, you need more memory -> use `double`.

Comment: All the essential information of an answer should be included in the answer. Information linked to may vanish or change, including images at imgur.com.